# Cannot sign in to Mac with VNC

Tags: remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I recently set a VNC Server on my Mac. It is always running and I have created the rules on my router for the port forwarding (5900).

When I am at home, and I connect to my Mac using its local IP address, I cannot sign in to my account. I am stuck at the login screen and when I enter my password, it says the password is incorrect. I have checked 3 times and I type it correctly. I have even tried to type it connecting the Apple keyboard to my computer but it still does not work.

When I am not at home, I connect to my Mac as usual using my world wide IP address. Everything look normal, but, actually i just cannot control anything on this computer. I do not see the mouse pointer but only the VNC square where the pointer is supposed to be. Also, the keyboard, this time does not work at all.

I have enabled the "can control everything" setting so...
What is happening

Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked the option VNC viewers may control screen with a password?

Comment: Yes and I set a password

Comment: Isn't Mac Screen Sharing basically VNC and compatible with VNC servers out of the box? I've never needed to do that but from everything I have heard you don't need to set up a separate VNC instance, just turn on screen sharing and set a password.

Comment: Yes it is but I wanted to get more settings so I enabled VNC Server also. But both do not work. One thing is that I do not know, when I connect with VNC, if its connect using VNC server or the local screen sharing app.

Comment: So... How can I do it ?

Comment: Did you try entering all number from numeric pad!? This worked for me, unfortunely I can't use numeric pad in mobile apps...